# How to create DataTemplate for several Image objects? (XAML)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I try to display some Images that are stored in ObservableCollection to the xaml page. It's easy to bind xaml object with one image:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

But how to display a set of images, if I don't know how much images there are? I think that I need to create a DataTemplate, but how it works?

Sorry, I'm not familiar with XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose one of several controls that commonly used to display multiple items, such as `LongListSelector`, `ItemsControl`, etc. Bind the control's ItemsSource to your `ObservableCollection` of image property. Then define `ItemTemplate` to tell the control how each item in the ItemsSource should be displayed. For example :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```